# SQLite returning groups with same number of rows in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have below SQLite query:

```
        select  
                product._id
                supermarket._id
                datetime(price.timestamp,'localtime') as LOCAL_TIMESTAMP,
                price.price
        from price inner join product on price.productid = product._id
                   inner join supermarket on price.supermarketid = supermarket._id

        order by price.productid, price.supermarketid, price.timestamp
```

Rows are ordered by productid, supermarketid and timestamp. Doing so they are grouped but not all pairs products-supermarket have the same timestamps so is it possible to obtain all pairs products-supermarket with the same number of timestamps? If a pair product-supermarket has not a timestamp, then set its price to 0 in the returned result.

For example, above query may return:

```
Product_A Supermarket_A "2014-03-10 00:00:00"   2.3
Product_A SUpermarket_A "2014-04-10 00:00:00"  15.0
Product_A SUpermarket_A "2014-04-20 00:00:00"  10.5

Product_B Supermarket_A "2014-01-01 00:00:00"  23.3
Product_B SUpermarket_A "2014-05-21 00:00:00"   1.0
```

and I would like to obtain:

```
Product_A Supermarket_A "2014-01-01 00:00:00"   0.0
Product_A Supermarket_A "2014-03-10 00:00:00"   2.3
Product_A SUpermarket_A "2014-04-10 00:00:00"  15.0
Product_A SUpermarket_A "2014-04-20 00:00:00"  10.5
Product_A SUpermarket_A "2014-05-21 00:00:00"   0.0

Product_B Supermarket_A "2014-01-01 00:00:00"  23.3
Product_B Supermarket_A "2014-03-10 00:00:00"   0.0
Product_B Supermarket_A "2014-04-10 00:00:00"   0.0
Product_B Supermarket_A "2014-04-20 00:00:00"   0.0
Product_B SUpermarket_A "2014-05-21 00:00:00"   1.0
```

In each product-supermarket pair appears all the timestamps (like an union). If a product-supermarket pair has not the timestamp, it is created and its price set to 0.0.

Is it possible to do in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all *possible* combinations of timestamps, join with the timestamps, but without a join condition. (The DISTINCTs are needed to avoid duplicates here.)

Then do an [outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join) with the prices:

```
SELECT productid,
       supermarketid,
       datetime(timestamp, 'localtime') AS local_timestamp,
       price.price
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT product._id     AS productid,
                      supermarket._id AS supermarketid
      FROM       product 
      INNER JOIN price       ON product._id         = price.productid
      INNER JOIN supermarket ON price.supermarketid = supermarket._id)
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT timestamp
            FROM price)
LEFT JOIN price USING (productid, supermarketid, timestamp)
```

This returns NULL for missing prices.
If you really want a zero, use `IFNULL(price.price, 0.0)` instead.

Comment: I am getting no values for column price. Also I am getting repeated rows. I have solved the repeated rows by using DISTINCT in the outer SELECT, I mean, first SELECT.

Comment: Finally it works. I have added DISTINCT in the first select (outer one) and also at the end I have replaced "AND LOCAL_TIMESTAMP = price.timestamp" by "AND LOCAL_TIMESTAMP=datetime(price.timestamp,'localtime')"

Comment: Fixed. I've moved the products/supermarkets into a subquery so that the DISTINCT is computed over as few data as possible. Joining on columns with the same name allows using USING.

Comment: Great! it works like a charm! One thing more, regarding to performance and execution time, I have executed this over a few registers no more than 10 in each table and it takes from 3ms to 20ms randomly each time I execute so I am worried when I will have a lot of registers. So will it take a lot of execution time over a lot of registers? Maybe if I create an index over price table it will speed up... Anyway many thanks. It works as I was expecting.

Comment: You should have an index on the timestamp column.